# How can I force enzyme to use props set with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've started learning TDD with TypeScript in React.
I have created an `<Avatar />` component. Its props should be of type `Props` as defined alongside `<Avatar />` component. While in normal development mode it works well when I test it with jest and enzyme it does not throw an error when props are not present. Below is my code.

I've tried to use `PropTypes` and attach it to `Avatar.propTypes` and it works. When props are not present jest/enzyme throws does not let the test pass. But it does not feel right to use TypeScript and PropTypes together as TypeScript is much more powerfull and omnipresent in the code.

Avatar.tsx:

```js
type Props = {
    imageUrl: string;
    alt: string;
};

const Avatar: React.SFC<Props> = ({imageUrl, alt}) => {
    ...
}
```

Avatar.test.tsx:

```js
describe('Avatar', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<Avatar />);
    });

    it('renders a <div />', () => {
        const result = wrapper.find('div').length;

        expect(result).toEqual(1);
    });

    ...
});
```

How can I make the test to fail the test when Props are invalid or missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is correctly typed and your avoiding the usage of `any` where ever possible the TypeScript compiler will yell at you, if there is a chance of missing props. (Also these props are marked as mandatory and the compiler should disallow you the usage of just `<Avatar />`).

But below you find an example on how it *could* work - *NOTE*: This has not been tested but is written out of memory.

For testing if the props are invalid, consider the following scenario:

```
// Avatar.tsx
type AvatarProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  alt: string;
}

const Avatar = (props: AvatarProps) => {

  return() {
    return (
      <div><p>{props.alt}</p></div>
    );
  }
}


// Avatar.test.tsx
describe('Avatar', () => {
  it("props are valid and defined", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Avatar imageUrl="foo.bar" alt="lorem ipsum" />);

    expect(wrapper.props().imageUrl).to.equal("foo.bar");
    // This what you are looking for
    expect(wrapper.props().imageUrl).not.toBeUndefined();
  });

  it("props are invalid", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Avatar imageUrl="foo.invalid" />);

    expect(wrapper.props().imageUrl).to.equal("foo.bar");
    expect(wrapper.props().alt).toBeUndefined();
  })
});
```

Please see enzyme docs: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/props.html